# CTabFolder: detect empty folder

Tags: java, tabs, swt

I would like to detect an empty SWT `CTabFolder` after closing some tabs.

My first approach was via an `CTabFolder2Adapter` listener and its `close` method. But this gets called before a tab is closed. So, it is not sufficient because tabs can be prevented from closing afterwards.

Another approach would be to add a dispose listener to each `CTabItem` which triggers a check for an empty folder.

Do you know of any cleaner way how to do this?

Comment: Is the a CTabFolder that you are creating? Nothing else is going to add a CTabFolder2Listener to your folder.

Comment: @greg-449 I am unsure if I understand correctly. But yes, I am using a CTabFolder with CTabItems.

Comment: I mean if you are creating the CTabFolder in your own code it is very unlikely that anything else will add a listener to the CTabFolder. So it is safe to use CTabFolder2Adapter.

Comment: @greg-449 Okay this is good to know. But the problem is that I did install such a listener; A dialog to ask if the tab should be closed. Of course, I could add some logic to this and decide if the (last) tab will be closed and the tab folder is therefore empty. But I was hoping for something cleaner.